# Ошибка при выполнении MySQL запроса

Tags: c++, mysql, freebsd

Код:

```
string sql;
connectionNOC = mysql_init(NULL); 
mysql_real_connect(connectionNOC,hostbase,userbase,passbase,namebase,3306,0,0)    sql ="SET NAMES utf8";

// Шаг 1
sql ="SET NAMES utf8";
if (mysql_query(connectionNOC, sql.c_str()) != 0){fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't execute SQL-query\n");exit(1);}; 

// Шаг 2
sql="select * from lanbshconfig";
if (mysql_query(connectionNOC, sql.c_str()) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't execute SQL-query\n",mysql_error(connectionNOC));
    exit(1);
};
```

На машине с Ubuntu выполняется корректно, на сервере с FreeBSD спотыкается на "//Шаг 2", с непонятной ошибкой, `mysql_error(connectionNOC)` не выводит её..

В чём я не прав?

Comment: К сожалению на машине с FreeBSD доступ только с консоли.. А там не очень умею это делать. Как можно поподробнее получить сообщения при запуске это программы? Что хотя бы не "нравится" ?

Comment: А как mysql_error что то выведет, если у вас в форматной строке fprintf нет ни одного подставляемого параметра (%)

Comment: Точно! Скосоглазил. Уже лучше: Error: can't execute SQL-query Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Промахнулся, не добавил отображение ошибки:

   > fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't execute SQL-query %s\n",mysql_error(connectionNOC));
2. Боремся с ошибкой:

   > "Error: can't execute SQL-query Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" на FreeBSD:

   после выполнения каждого запроса необходимо "сохранять" результат запроса

   ```
   result=mysql_store_result(connectionNOC);
   ```
3. Во FreeBSD не достаточно "выбрать базу" при выполнении

   ```
    mysql_real_connect(connectionNOC,hostbase,userbase,passbase,namebase,3306,0,0).
   ```

   Пришлось дополнительно её "перевыбирать" в запросом. Странные особенности...

Итоговый правильный код:

```
string sql;
connectionNOC = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(connectionNOC,hostbase,userbase,passbase,namebase,3306,0,0)

sql ="use noc";
if (mysql_query(connectionNOC, sql.c_str()) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't execute SQL-query\n");
    exit(1);
};      
result=mysql_store_result(connectionNOC);    

// Шаг 1
sql ="SET NAMES utf8";
if (mysql_query(connectionNOC, sql.c_str()) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error:  can't execute SQL-query\n");exit(1);
};      
result=mysql_store_result(connectionNOC);    

// Шаг 2
sql="select * from lanbshconfig";
if (mysql_query(connectionNOC, sql.c_str()) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't execute   SQL-query %s\n",mysql_error(connectionNOC));
    exit(1);
};
```